# Morphological Relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

Say I have a database setup with the following tables:

```
Project    User     Properties
-------    ----     ---------- 
id         id       id
name       name     key
                    value
                    owner_type
                    owner_id
```

I want both the Project and the User entities to be able to have properties. The owner_type field on properties matches, for example, the tables names and the owner_id matches some row in the owner_type-table.

I have not been able to figure out how to do this in Entity Framework. I think I need to write some kind of custom relationship, but I cannot figure out how.

**Edit:**
I am not looking for a one-to-one or one-to-many relationship. I understand how that works. This problem is solvable with a pivot table for each Entity that can have Properties, but this is not what I want.

I am looking for a relationship that does something like this (perhaps using computed columns):

```
--- Select the properties for Project `10`
SELECT * FROM Properties WHERE owner_type = 'ProjectEntityName' AND owner_id = 10
--- Select the properties for User `2`
SELECT * FROM Properties WHERE owner_type = 'UserEntityName' AND owner_id = 2
```

I know that Laravel has these relationships in Eloquent, but I need them in Entity Framework. It is no problem that is not some default supported thing, but I want to be able to access the Properties using a syntax like this:

```
var project_properties = cx.Project.Where(p => p.id = 2).Properties;
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid mapping to the system tables that are specific to Sql Server database.

Properties belong to a class, so create the Class entity in your model, with an id and a name.

Use inheritance, create a base object for 'Project' and 'User', for example 'DbObject', that as attributes 'id' and 'name'.

Add a class_id field in your DbObject table as a foreign key on the Class Table.

Add a class_id field in your Properties table as a foreign key on the Class Table.

In your object model, class Properties has a navigation property on a Class.

```
Class
-------
id
name

DbObject   Properties
-------    ---------- 
id         id
class_id   class_id
name       key
           value
           owner_type
           owner_id

Project : DbObject   User : DbObject 
-------              ----  
(project             (user
specific             specific
attributes)          attributes)
```